# How to convert oracle timestamp to postgres?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

How to convert the oracle timestamp to postgres timestamp,we have a values in oracle data base as below,

```
15-JUN-2014 01.00.00.0000 PM
```

I have stored as varchar in postgres/Greenplum. How can I cast to timestamp in postgres,

Output required As below ,

```
15-06-2014 13.00.00.0000
```

As 24 hrs format.

Comment: Timestamps don't have "a format" - neither in Oracle nor in Postgres (or in any other DBMS). How are you transferring the data? How are you connecting the two databases?

Comment: from oracle we are generating csv files and loading into greenplum in that case i am not able to convert am/pm into 24 hrs format in postgress/greenplum.

Comment: The why don't you create the CSV file with the correct timestamp format right away?

Comment: total size of file is more than 100 gb , i dont want to re-create again by sitting more than 2 -3 days :)

Answer (score 3):

Timestamps are timestamps. They represent a date (incl. time) using an internal representation. But you can convert timestamps to/from strings using various [formats](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924). For example, if you need to display them or in order to export your data to an other software requiring some specific representation.

In the following code for Oracle, I convert from a string to a timestamp ([`TO_TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm)) using a format corresponding to your first example. Then I "convert back" that timestamp to a string ([`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)) using an other format corresponding to your second representation:

```
-- Convert a string to a timestamp
WITH sample_data AS 
  (SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('15-JUN-2014 01.00.00.0000 PM', 
                       'DD-MON-YYYY HH12.MI.SS.FF4 PM') ts FROM DUAL)

-- Convert a timestamp to a string using a format corresponding
-- to "15-06-2014 13.00.00.0000"
SELECT TO_CHAR(ts, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24.MI.SS.FF4') as result FROM sample_data;
```

Producing (the *string*):

```
result
15-06-2014 13.00.00.0000
```

Please note that you can convert from string to date in PostgreSQL too using (almost?) exactly the same [date functions and formats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

Comment: Still not working it's not converting to 24hrs format `select TO_TIMESTAMP(event_timestamp,'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS.FF4')::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE from jiodba.ext_WFA_ACCOUNTING_MSG limit 100 --"2014-07-01 12:01:18" `

Comment: this solution strips the 'PM' from the end of the timestamp. How can you maintain the Oracle formatting in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT To_timestamp(event_timestamp,'DD-MON-YY HH12.MI.SS.SSSS AM.PM')::timestamp without time zone
FROM jiodba.ext_wfa_accounting_msg limit 1000;
```

Please find the answer